# Foreach creating multi-level instead of single level array in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to gather a group of term_id's output in a foreach and create an array from them. I then want to update the taxonomy with the values in the array however the array is being created as multi-level. My code is as follows:

```
$updateTax = array();
foreach ($featuresArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key = 'en_value') {

        $termResult = get_term_by('name', $value['en_value'], $taxonomy);
        $term = $termResult->term_id;
        $updateTax[] = array($term);

    }
}
```

...which then gives this output:

```
var_dump($updateTax);

array(29) {

 [0]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(111) } [1]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(116) } [2]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(124) } [3]=> array(1) {
  ...
  [0]=> int(408) } [25]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(447) } [26]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(520) } [27]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(593) } [28]=> array(1) {
  [0]=> int(628) }

  }
```

...but I was expecting the following:

```
array(29) {

 [0]=> int(111) } 
 [1]=> int(116) }
 [2]=> int(124) }
 [3]=> int(125) }
 ...
```

Bit puzzled so could do with some guidance please. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following line, where you are creating an individual array for each `$term`:

```
$updateTax[] = array($term);
```

With this:

```
$updateTax[] = $term;
```